# Refreshing a div after click event animation

Tags: jquery

I have a web page that plays a phone conversation after a user clicks a keypad, along with images of the two having the discussion animating in size when each one of them is speaking. I want the user to be able to replay the audio/animation (by clicking the keypad again) after the initial audio/animation completes. I want the div to refresh after the audio/animation completes but because this is not a timed event (it depends on when the user clicks the keypad) I cannot use the setInterval method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$.fn.speak = function(){
            $(this).animate({
                height:'+=57px',
                width:'+=57px'
            }, 500);
        }

        $.fn.stopSpeak = function(){
            $(this).animate({
                height:'-=57px',
                width:'-=57px'
            }, 500);
        }

        function animateSpeakers(){
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(4150).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(4700).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(100).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(100).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(10250).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(10250).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(5000).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(5000).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(6500).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(6500).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(4500).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(4500).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(11250).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(11250).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(9750).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(9750).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(7000).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(7000).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(500).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(500).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(18250).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(18250).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(3250).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(3250).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(7500).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(7500).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(500).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(500).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(30100).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(30100).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(17750).stopSpeak();

        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(17750).speak();
        $('#claim-rep-5_5').delay(26750).stopSpeak();

        $('#insured-5_5').delay(26750).speak();
        $('#insured-5_5').delay(2250).stopSpeak();

        $('.click-next').delay(175250).fadeIn(1000);
        }

        var processing = false;

        $('#keypad').on('click', function(){
            $('.click-next').hide();
            if (!processing) {
                processing = true;
                animateSpeakers(function(){
                processing = false; 
                });
            }

        });


<section>
        <div id="page-title">
            <h2 class="lineheight24">Putting it All Together: <br>Five Customer Service Scenarios</h2>
        </div><!-- end page-title -->

        <div id="page-identifier">
            <p class="page-number">Page 5.9</p>
        </div><!-- end page-identifier -->

        <div class="clear"></div><br>

        <p class="bold">Scenario 1: &nbsp;Auto Theft - THE NEXT DAY...</p><br>

        <img onclick="document.getElementById('call-1b').play()" id="keypad" class="float-left" src="IMG/graphic-5_5.gif" alt="" style="margin:13px 0 0 25px; cursor:pointer;" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <object id="audioObject" type="audio/x-mpeg" data="call-1b.mp3" autoplay="false" style="display:none;">
                <param name="src" value="AUDIO/scenarios/call-1a.mp3" />
                <param name="controller" value="false" />
                <param name=autoplay" value="false" />
                <param name="autostart" value="false" />
            </object>

            <script>
                document.getElementById('keypad').onclick = function() {document.getElementById('audioObject').play() };
            </script>

        <![endif]-->

         <p class="col-400 italic" style="margin:30px 0 0 40px;">The following day after completing your research, you place a follow-up phone call to Ms. Kaletta. Click on the telephone keypad to place the call. (To replay, click the keypad again).</p>

        <div class="clear"></div><br>

        <img id="claim-rep-5_5" class="absolute" src="IMG/scenario-images/5_5/claim-rep-5_5.jpg" alt="insurance claim representative" width="173" style="top:315px; left:50px;" />

        <img id="insured-5_5" class="absolute" src="IMG/scenario-images/5_5/insured-5_5.jpg" alt="insured" width="173" style="top:315px; left:375px;" />

        <p class="click-next absolute" style="top:540px; left:25px;">Click next to continue.</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: Without telling us how you built this in the first place, how would you expect anyone to know how to fix it?

Comment: Post some code first, then we have something to talk about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the div to refresh after the audio/animation completes but because this is not a timed event (it depends on when the user clicks the keypad)

You can hook up the refresh function to the `complete` parameter of:

- the `fadeIn` function: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- the `animate` function: http://api.jquery.com/animate/